# Devexpress GridView Selected Row

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress, filtering

I have a gridList in my c# project. There is more than 100 000 records in my gridList. I want to do some  operation on filtered rows. For example I filtered gridList by 'name' column ,then I want to select all filtered rows. How can I do this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you want to select all visible rows, or just select some of them and then perform some action with selected rows? Also - is your project Winforms, WPF or ASP? Because DevExpress has a lots of frameworks.

Comment: My project is Winforms. I want to select rows which are filtered on devexpress gridview. For example;   

for (int i = 0; i < gridViewList.RowCount; i++)
            {
                // Check filteredRow[i]
            }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To traverse grid rows (with grouping, sorting and filtering taking into account) use the following approach:

```
void TraverseRows(ColumnView view) {
    for (int i = 0; i < view.DataRowCount; i++) {
        object row =  view.GetRow(i);
        // do something with row
    }
}
```

P.S. Please read the [Traversing Rows](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument742) article for details.

Comment: Thank you. This is best answer which I want.

Comment: I have one more question to you. I write code block like upper part, but I have a problem about casting. My code block is           


for (int i = 0; i < view.DataRowCount; i++)
            {
                var row = view.GetRow(i);
                drTemp = (DSFollow.FollowRequestsRow)row;
                
                if (selectRemove)
                    drTemp.is_selected = selectRemove;
                dtTemp.AddFollowRequestsRow(drTemp);
            } 
when drTemp casting, I have a error message.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to set `OptionsSelection.MultiSelect = true` property of your `GridView`.

Then, to select all filtered rows you can use `SelectAll()` method of your `GridView` after applying your filter.

Answer (score 0):

I find another answer for tihs problem:

```
void TraverseRows(ColumnView view,bool selectRemove)
{
    dtTemp = new Data.Medical.Follow.DSFollow.FollowRequestsDataTable();
    for (int i = 0; i < gridViewList.RowCount; i++)
    {
        DataRow row = gridViewList.GetDataRow(gridViewList.GetVisibleRowHandle(i));
        row["is_selected"] = selectRemove;
        dtTemp.AddFollowRequestsRow((DSFollow.FollowRequestsRow)row);
    }
}
```

Comment: In fact, it's not exactly the same as 'I want to select rows which are filtered` you've talked about earlier, as it has nothing common with 'selected' grid rows in the terms of DevExpress GridView.

Comment: My English is not yet to tell my problem. So that i couldn't tell my problem rightly